# Eclipse : how to prevent it from loading all the open files on startup?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I had 100+ files open in the previous session, then closed eclipse. On a restart, eclipse just hangs with extremely high mem usuage. This problem doesn't happen with only 50 files opened.

How to prevent eclipse from loading all the previously opened files on startup? It would make more sense that the files are loaded on demand, i.e. load when focused.

I am using CDT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

opened a bug on eclipse, after the help from there, it turns out this is caused by the vrapper plugin I installed. For more details, https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=377368

Answer (score 1):

When the Eclipse is open, close those projects which you dont want for now. Right Click on the project name and select "Close Project". Next time you restart the Eclipse the closed projects should not get loaded.

Comment: I already closed all the projects I don't want. Actually, I only have 1 project open.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible. Eclipse will always restore the same state after a restart.

You can mitigate the effects with little fuzz by

- closing projects (right click the project you're not working on, select `Close Project`
- closing unrelated projects (right click the project you're working on, select `Close Unrelated Projects`
- **using Mylyn!** Mylyn will ensure that files you stopped working on will be automatically closed. (But it does more than that. See for more info e.g. [help.tasktop.com](http://help.tasktop.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.mylyn.help.ui/Mylyn/User_Guide/User-Guide.html) and [www.tasktop.com (pdf)](http://www.tasktop.com/pdfs/docs/tutorials/2009-03-mylyn-tutorial.pdf)) It takes some time getting used to it, but I eventually fell in love with it. 
  If you don't switch tasks that often, you can just create one general task, activate it and keep working in that one forever.